# jquery left navigation menu

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have a navigation menu on left and I am using jquery to slide down the sub menu when I click on h3 it is going right for me as it is showing the hidden menu when I click it but if I click on second h3 it also opens but does not close the previous h3 content.

here is a [link](http://jsbin.com/welcome/69893/edit) to see what I am talking about.

Thanks to roXon my problem got solved but now when I am adding a hyperlink to inside h3 tag it 's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will allow you to:

- Hide all opened before opening the clicked one
- Toggle (show/hide) on one "button"

http://jsbin.com/welcome/69899/edit

```
$(document).ready(function (){


$('.hide').hide();
$('.arrowlistmenu li:has(".hide")').find('h3').click(function() {
    var el = $(this).next('.hide'),
    check = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.hide').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
});


});
```

Comment: @Chandru! you're welcome! don't forget to accept answers that helped you in your course :) (review the old ones too) thx

Comment: some problem again when I am adding a hyperlink inside h3 it's not working.